# SQL Server 2008 - Trouble when create dynamic column as the sample

Tags: sql-server-2008

Currently, I'm having a trouble when create dynamic columns as following sample:

```
ColumnA   Mon_Year    Value
  'A'      8/2016      2
  'B'      8/2016      3
  'A'      9/2016      4
  'B'      9/2016      5
  'B'      10/2016     6
```

What I want to have a table with format like this:

```
ColumnA   8/2016    9/2016    10/2016
  'A'        2        4         0
  'B'        3        5         6
```

I tried to create tmp table and add columns after each month, but I cannot have the right result.

Does anyone help me to solve this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pivot. Refer my code below. Hope to help, my friend :)

```
create table Test(ColumnA varchar(10), Month_Year date, Value int)

insert into Test values('A', '2016/08/10', 2)
insert into Test values('B', '2016/08/10', 3)
insert into Test values('A', '2016/09/10', 4)
insert into Test values('B', '2016/09/10', 5)

DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(FORMAT(Month_Year, 'MM/yyyy'))
               FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Month_Year FROM test) x ORDER BY Month_Year FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM 
             (
             SELECT ColumnA, FORMAT(Month_Year, ''MM/yyyy'') AS Month_Year, Value 
             FROM test
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 SUM(Value)
                 FOR Month_Year IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p;' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```